# Show div on click by Jquery only apply to 1 div at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and in my loop I have a link that is clickable to toggle a div to show and hide the content, since this is within the loop it uses the same class for each item in the loop so when I toggle one link it shows the content for all.

```
<div class="additional-info">Additinal Information</div>

<div class="additional-info-box">
   <?php echo $additional_info; ?>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $(".additional-info").click(function () {
            $(".additional-info-box").toggle();
        });
    })
</script>
```

So the additional-info class and the additional-info-box gets generated for each post, but when I click on any of the additional-info divs every additional info box gets shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapped :

```
<div class="additional-info">
     Additinal Information
    <div class="additional-info-box">
      <?php echo $additional_info; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $(".additional-info").click(function () {
            $(this).find(".additional-info-box").toggle();
        });
    })
</script>
```

with that only the `.additional-info` clicked will show their content.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tgc7B/)

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't seem to work. I just tried it and all of the .additional-info boxes still open.

Comment: See the live demo. but Are you creatting this div dynamically?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a query with wordpress, it works for your demo but not on my site, does that have to doal with it being queried?

Comment: @Greenhoe Don't worry, I'm glad to helped you.